# MySQL query to get first unique values of one column on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following SQL query which queries my tickets, ticketThreads, users and threadStatus tables:

```
SELECT tickets.threadId, ticketThreads.threadSubject, tickets.ticketCreatedDate,  ticketThreads.threadCreatedDate, threadStatus.threadStatus, users.name
FROM 
tickets 
INNER JOIN 
ticketThreads
ON
tickets.threadId = ticketThreads.threadId
INNER JOIN
threadStatus 
ON
ticketThreads.threadStatus = threadStatus.id
INNER JOIN
users
ON
users.id = ticketThreads.threadUserId
WHERE
tickets.ticketId = ticketThreads.lastMessage
AND 
ticketThreads.threadStatus != 3
ORDER BY
tickets.ticketCreatedDate
DESC
```

The abridged version of what this returns is:

```
threadId | 
----------
1        |
2        |
```

This works fine, and is what I expect, however to clean up the code and database slightly I need to remove the ticketThreads.lastMessage column.

If I remove the line `WHERE tickets.ticketId = ticketThreads.lastMessage` then  this is an abridged version of what is returned:

```
threadId | 
----------
1        |
2        |
1        |
```

What I need to do then is edit the query above to enable me to select the highest unique value for each threadId value in the tickets database.

I know about `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` but can't figure how to get them into my query above.

The relevant parts of the tables are shown below:

**tickets**

```
ticketId | ticketUserId | threadId 
-------------------------------
1        | 1            | 1
2        | 1            | 2
3        | 1            | 1
```

**ticketThreads**

```
threadId | lastMessage  | threadStatus
-------------------------------
1        | 3            | 4
2        | 2            | 1
```

I hope all the above is clear and makes sense

Comment: This question (and its variants) is only asked *every single day*.

Comment: thanks for the helpful answer :-) I've read many of the answers here, I'm asking here as my last point of call as I am finding it hard to implement into my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need the `ticket` with the highest id per each thread? Your problem is actually very easy variant of [greatest record per group problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group). No need for any subqueries. Basicaly you have two options, which both should perform much better than your query, the second be faster (please post the actual durations in your db!):

#### 1. Standard compliant query, but slower:

```
SELECT t1.threadId, ticketThreads.threadSubject, t1.ticketCreatedDate,  
    ticketThreads.threadCreatedDate, threadStatus.threadStatus, users.name
FROM tickets as t1
LEFT JOIN tickets as t2 
    ON t1.threadId = t2.threadId AND t1.ticketId < t2.ticketId
JOIN ticketThreads ON t1.threadId = ticketThreads.threadId
JOIN threadStatus ON ticketThreads.threadStatus = threadStatus.id
JOIN users ON users.id = ticketThreads.threadUserId
WHERE t2.threadId is NULL
    AND ticketThreads.threadStatus != 3
ORDER BY t1.ticketCreatedDate DESC
```

This one joins the `tickets` table two times, which can make it a bit slower for big tables.

#### 2. Faster, but uses MySQL extension to standard SQL:

```
set @prev_thread := NULL;

SELECT t.threadId, ticketThreads.threadSubject, t.ticketCreatedDate,  
    ticketThreads.threadCreatedDate, threadStatus.threadStatus, users.name
FROM tickets as t
JOIN ticketThreads ON t.threadId = ticketThreads.threadId
JOIN threadStatus ON ticketThreads.threadStatus = threadStatus.id
JOIN users ON users.id = ticketThreads.threadUserId
WHERE ticketThreads.threadStatus != 3
    AND IF(IFNULL(@prev_thread, -1) = @prev_thread := t.threadId, 0, 1)
ORDER BY t.threadId, t.ticketId DESC,
    t.ticketCreatedDate DESC
```

Here, we perform one pass scan on ordered joined data, using auxiliary mysql variable `@prev_thread` to filter only the first (in the given order) ticket for each thread (the one with highest ticketId).